# How to convert or typecast UIViewController to AnyClass in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, casting, ios8

I just want to convert any `UIViewController` subclass to `AnyClass` for checking from the `isKindOfClass` method because this method takes `AnyClass` as argument.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using old `Objective-C` API, you can use the `as` or `is` keyword in swift.

```
if let controller = yourViewController as? SomeClass {
    // use controller, is already casted to SomeClass
}

if yourViewController is SomeClass {
    let controller = yourViewController as! SomeClass
    // use controller now
}
```

**ADDING**:
If the memory addresses are different, the objects are not equal. Try to check for the `topViewController` type as I mentioned in the answer.

```
if let topViewController = appDelegateObj.navigationController.topViewController as? YOUR_VIEW_CONTROLLER_CLASS {
     // do something 
}
```

Comment: I want to do this

if appDelegateObj.navigationController!.topViewController! == myViewController {
            // Not getting true even both are same but memory references are different
        }else {
            
            // Need to handle something else
        }

Answer (score 1):

```
func someMethod (someClass : AnyClass) {
   if someClass is YourClass {
     someClass.someMethodOfYourClass()
   }
}
```

To use this method

```
class YouClass: UIViewController {

   func something() {
    someMethod(self)    // sending itself (a.k.a) YourClass

   }
}
```

Hope this helps

Edit based on comment :

```
let controller = appDelegateObj.navigationController!.topViewController

if controller is ClassName {
    // controller good  to use
 }
```

Comment: Okay @GopalDevra My name is Akshansh haha.

Comment: hey @Akshansh,
yes it is working 
but Here ClassName could be anything in runtime
It is working with the fixed class name
Do you have any Idea to convert to any UIViewController class to specific
without checking and converting.

Comment: See if you get `AnyClass` as an argument, then you will have to check and convert. But to do it without checks, you can specify method parameter to be of type `someMethod(className : YourClass) { ... }`

Comment: could you elaborate it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115301/discussion-between-akshansh-thakur-and-gopal-devra).

Comment: @AkshanshThakur not working, cant convert uiviewcontroller into AnyClass. why?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I reached at this solution

```
let name = NSStringFromClass((vcAnyObj?.classForCoder)!) 
let name2 = NSStringFromClass((appDelegateObj.navigationController!.topViewController?.classForCoder)!) 

if name == name2 { 
print("same view controller") 
}else { 
print("different view controller") 

}
```

Comment: You could even override the `==` operator to make a correct comparison. If two viewControllers are of the same class, this doesn't mean that they are equal